Women controlled by alien/demon is stripping in car
There is a woman alone in a car who starts removing her clothes but slowly it is obvious there is some supernatural entity who is doing it and is also pleasuring the woman till she is almost naked and then the alien/demon is shown. The woman then screams and is presumably killed.
English movie. somewhere between 1970-1990. white woman. was listening to some music inside car i think. and either her clothes were blue or the car was
Can anyone identify this movie?

Is that all you remember? It sounds like a horror movie by that description. When/where did you see it? Where was it made & in what language did you hear it? What did the woman/car/demon look like? The more details you can provide, the better the chance others can identify it.

English movie. somewhere between 1970-1990. white woman. was listening to some music inside car i think. and either her clothes were blue or the cae was

That's better.. Select the little edit link below the question tags & add it into the question where it has better visibility.

It sounds like the movie Trick or Treat (1986)

Sammi Curr was a famous, devil-worshiping rock star who died under mysterious circumstances. Now he wants to come back to life. Doing so requires possessing radio wave & automobiles and making a few human sacrifices.IMDB








Clip: Trick or Treat' (1986)

This is it. God bless you dude
